# Что такое веб-контейнер и веб-сервер?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, j2ee

Разобраюсь с общей архитектурой веб-приложений. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как взаимосвязаны следующие понятия:

1. сервер (приложение)
2. веб-контейнер
3. веб-приложение

Если я правильно понимаю, то на сервере (приложение) должен быть запущен веб-контейнер, внутри которого уже будет запущено веб-приложение. Но у меня остаются вопросы:

- в одном веб-контейнере может быть запущено только одно веб-приложение или несколько?
- на сервере может быть запущен только один веб-контейнер или несколько?
- фронтенд и бекенд это веб-приложения? Они запускаются в разных веб-контейнерах? На разных серверах или можно на одном?
- для веб-приложений работающих в облачных сервисах (AWS, Azure) эти концепции остаются в силе или там по другому?

Comment: Фронтенд это программа, являющаяся клиентом бекенда и отправляющая запросы к нему (обычно браузер с запущенными в нём скриптами на странице), бекенд это программа обрабатывающая запросы фронтенда (обычно веб-сервер). Веб-контейнер это специфичный для J2EE термин, и не-Java программисты таким термином не пользуются

Comment: @andreymal Они запускаются в разных веб-контейнерах? На разных серверах или можно на одном?

Comment: Фронтенд обычно запускается на устройстве пользователя

Comment: Контейнер предполагает что в нем может быть несколько независимых веб приложений. На сервере может быть запущено несколько разных контейнеров, Вы же можете запустить 2 программы на одном компьютере...

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите [первоисточники](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/819-3669/bnabq/index.html):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Веб сервер, это нечто обрабатывающее запросы с протоколом `http`
2. Веб контейнер (ака сервлет контейнер) - часть веб сервера обрабатывающее запросы согласно спецификации Java Servlet/JSP
3. Сервер приложений - нечто обрабатывающее запросы не только с протоколом `http`, но и другие, например RMI, SMTP, JMX и т.д.